# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - package org.netbeans.lib.awtextra does not exist on netbeans

Tags: java

I got this message every time but I can't understand. Please help. "  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)" what this line means?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - package org.netbeans.lib.awtextra does not exist
    at coderhasib.ui.MainWindow.initComponents(MainWindow.java:1)
    at coderhasib.ui.MainWindow.<init>(MainWindow.java:28)
    at coderhasib.ui.MainWindow$10.run(MainWindow.java:398)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: First, I would strongly suggest that you don't even *try* to run code that doesn't compile. Compile it first, fix any errors, and once it's compiled without any errors, *then* run it. (Aside from anything else, your IDE may well be able to help you more with compiler errors.)

Comment: Could you share your code? We don't know what are you trying to do, I assume that is something with GUI. Do you have code errors/warnings before run it? Which ones? Please edit your question and probably we can help you

Comment: Thank you sir, I compiled the source code and I get " at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)" error.

Comment: Sir, I need to know why to give this error. I am using zorin os. Is that a permission issue?